# Odd error compiling Android Studio project

Tags: android

I made an app conjugating spanish verbs some time ago. There are alot af string arrays (the array.xml is 582 lines long). The Main Activity got about 95 different views. Which is more than recommended, I know.
I did it a few years ago, not sure which version of Android Studio I used. Now I've updated Android Studio to:
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

It works very well, but if I add or remove one array the app reads the wrong arrays (So if I read an Array called 'spanish_er' it instead reads the array called 'button_names' (and the app crashes on start due to array out of bounds error).
If I add or remove a view from my main activity the SupportActionBar and the options menu disappears (but the app still runs ok).
I don't know if this is a memory issue or what the problem is. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You forgot to add the full error message you got your question. Please do so and add it in text form (not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to solve this problem. My guess is that I've updated studio too many times and somewhere along the updates there was a problem. So I just created a new project and copied in my code in the new project and it worked perfectly.